# What kind of papaver is this?

Tags: identification

I would like to know the exact species of this plant frpm papaver family:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Zone is 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a common poppy (common name) and its Latin name is Papaver rhoeas https://www.brc.ac.uk/plantatlas/plant/papaver-rhoeas